# Delete filter record in objectify datastore

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-endpoints

i want to delete record where company_id is "****" and gamer_id is "****".
How to write query for this .

`public List<CompanyGamer> unfollowcompany(CompanyGamerForm CompanyGamerForm) throws NotFoundException {
        String company_id = CompanyGamerForm.getCompany_id();
        String gamer_id = CompanyGamerForm.getGamer_id();
        Iterable<Key<CompanyGamer>> allKeys = ofy().load().type(CompanyGamer.class).filter("company_id=", company_id).filter("gamer_id=", gamer_id).keys();
        ofy().delete().keys(allKeys); }`
Please let me know what should be define in return ?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the Objectify documentation for Queries https://github.com/objectify/objectify/wiki/Queries at the bottom of section "Executing Queries". "You can query for just keys, which will return Key objects much more efficiently than fetching whole objects"

```
Iterable<Key<Gamercompany>> allKeys = ofy().load().type(Gamercompany.class).filter("company_id=", compnyid).filter("gamer_id=",gamer_id).keys();
```

And then you can delete all entities corresponding to the keys:

```
ofy().delete().keys(allKeys);
```

Or if you do want to execute the query that returns the entities and not the keys, you could iterate over the Query and do:

```
ofy().delete().entity(thing);        // asynchronous
```

or

```
ofy().delete().entity(thing).now();  // synchronous
```

However it would be less efficient than the first way.

Comment: i tried. but it is not working . i have edited my question , i have added whole Api method . please check.

Comment: What do you get with allKeys?? Can you iterate over it?